# Modular inverse - java coding

Tags: java, math

Please help. I've been working on this non stop and can't get it right. The issue I'm having is that the output I'm getting for the inverse is always 1.

This is the code that I have (it computes GCD and trying to modify so it also computes a^-1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scratchwork
{


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        long n, a, on, oa;
        long gcd = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter your dividend:");
        n= keyboard.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Please enter your divisor:");
        a= keyboard.nextLong();

        on= n;
        oa= a;

        while (a!= 0)
                {gcd=a;
                    a= n% a;
                    n= gcd;
        }

        System.out.println("Results: GCD(" + odd + ", " + odr + ") = " + gcd);

        long vX; vS; vT; vY; q; vR; vZ; m; b;

        vX = n; vY=a;
        vS = 0; vT = 1; m=0; b=0;
        while (a != 0)
        {
            m=vT;;
                b=vX;
                q = n / a;
                vR = vS - q*vT;
                tZ = n - q*a;
                vS = vT; n = da;
                vT = tY; dY = vZ;

        }

         if (d>1) System.out.println("Inverse does not exist.");
        else System.out.println("The inverse of "+oa+" mod "+on+" is "+vT);
    } 
}
```

Comment: For those who, like me, haven't heard of the modular inverse, see: [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) and [Extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) on Wikipedia.

Comment: You might need to debug this yourself. Try printing out the variables at each step through the loop and making sure they match your hand-calculation steps (you have tried doing it by hand, right?).

Comment: I have done the work by hand multiple times and it works out. I try to put it in and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Good, but you also need to print out the variables at each step (say, at the end of your second while loop) and find the very first time when they differ from your hand-calculation.

Comment: I'm trying that but it doesn't want to work. Like I said I'm new at this, only took an intro course 2.5 years ago and now for my final math class we need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the variables declaration? If you mix integer with double, your numbers can be rounded. Anyway, if you only want the inverse, juste use `Math.pow(a, -1);`

Also, in the second loop, you never set "a" so it will loop forever:

```
while (a != 0)
        {
            m=vT;;
                b=vX;
                q = n / a;
                vR = vS - q*vT;
                tZ = n - q*a;
                vS = vT; n = da;
                vT = tY; dY = vZ;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted does not declare most of the variables it uses and thus dues not compile. Most importantly, the variable `v` it uses to output the result is neither defined nor assigned to anywhere in the posted code - whatever it contains has nothing to do with the calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm a complete newbie at this.

Comment: I just realized I made a typo there, in my coding it actually says vT. I think I may have accidentally erased it when editing it to put it on here.

Comment: @Andro: editing the code before putting it here is the worst thing you can do. As it is, it still does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

@Justin,
Thanks. I was able to figure out how to print out the variables in each loop. I basically had to put my loop up with the GCD loop...that was it. 2 weeks worth of work and I had just to move where the loop was.

It works! I'm sorry but I'm doing a happy dance over here.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  You should mark your post as an answer so others can quickly see that you solved your problem.  Better yet, edit your answer to show the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Python that should be easily translatable into Java:

```
def euclid(x, y):
    """Given x < y, find a and b such that a * x + b * y = g where, g is the
    gcd of x and y.  Returns (a,b,g)."""
    assert x < y
    assert x >= 0
    assert y > 0

    if x == 0:
        # gcd(0,y) = y
        return (0, 1, y)
    else:
        # Write y as y = dx + r
        d = y/x
        r = y - d*x

        # Compute for the simpler problem.
        (a, b, g) = euclid(r, x)

        # Then ar + bx = g     -->
        #      a(y-dx) + bx = g    -->
        #      ay - adx + bx = g    -->
        #      (b-ad)x + ay = g
        return (b-a*d, a, g)

def modinv(x, n):
    (a, b, g) = euclid(x%n, n)
    assert g == 1

    # a * x + b * n = 1 therefore
    # a * x = 1 (mod n)
    return a%n
```

It uses the stack, but Euclid's algorithm takes O(log n) steps so you won't have a stack overflow unless your numbers are astronomically high.  One could also translate it into a non-recursive version with some effort.